# Complexity of FFT Algorithm

Tags: computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

OkayI am using iterative FFT algorithm and I have found that since there are 2N computation per stage and there are logN stages the complexity should be **O(2NlogN)**
I can reduce the number of multiplication per stage to N/2
So the total complexity becomes **O((3N/2)logN)**

So discarding the constant factors the algorithm still has complexity **O(NlogN)**?

Comment: correct, and welcome. I don't think this question is appropriate for math.SE though. It doesn't have enough details to benefit future visitors...

Answer (score 1):

For any constant $c$. $O(c N\log N)=O(N\log N)$.